# What url-patern should I use in ADF in the web.xml to protect a page? The URL shows the previous page.

Tags: security, web.xml, oracle-adf, jaas, url-pattern

I have the following security constraint in my **web.xml** file to make the **help.jspx** page available only for some specific users.

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>protected</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/help</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>admin_role</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

As you can see, **faces/help** is the pattern that is protected. But let me explian what happens in ADF.

> 1. If I run the **home.jspx** I will get this url: http://mydomain.com/something/faces/home
> 2. Then, if I navigate to the page **about.jspx**, the url will still show the same http://mydomain.com/something/faces/home
> 3. Now if I navigate to **help.jspx**, the url will show the previous page name **"about"** http://mydomain.com/something/faces/about, so I will be able to view **help.jspx** even if I have not logged in yet.
> 4. This is not it, now if I navigate to **home.jspx** once again, the url will show the previous page **"help"** http://mydomain.com/something/faces/help, so I will be asked to log in before I am able to access to the **"home"** page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to refresh the URL so the new URL gets the new page name on it. Go to your task flow and add

```
<redirect/>
```

inside the view tags that you want their URL's to be refreshed.

```
 <view id="help_id">
   <page>/help.jspx</page>
   <redirect/>
 </view>
```

This is what the Jdev help says about the redirect tag:

**Redirect**:
Choose true if the ADF controller should issue an HTTP redirect for a view activity request. The redirected request creates a new browser URL for the view activity. The original view URL is no longer used.